# Добавление переменной в строку

Tags: python, url

Например, у меня есть ссылка. 
Мне нужно добавить содержимое переменной a в ссылку между / /.
Как это реализовать на Python?

```
a="class"
schedule_url="https://www.example.com/ a /get"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a="class"
schedule_url="https://www.example.com/{}/get".format(a)
```